# Whats differnece between Symbol Table and Branch/Jump/Virtual Method Table in Context of C/C++

Tags: c++

Whats differnece between Symbol Table and Branch/Jump/Virtual Method Table in Context of C/C++ ? 
As both keeps the reference of the routines from library/executable module. What's major difference between the two ?

Comment: AFAIK there is no particular symbol table in context of C/C++. Symbol tables _may_ occur in context of some particular compiler implementation (not necessary a compiler for C/C++).

Comment: What is the context of "C/C++"? These are different programming languages. I'd think that your question has not much to do with C.

Answer (score 3):

The symbol table is a module of the compiler, the virtual method table is a way to implement virtual function.  I'd rather explain what they have in common excepted the word table in their name (short answer nothing) than how their differ. For a start they don't exist at the same time, they serve different purpose, they contain different information.